# Is there a way to attach a message to a tg:// handler url for telegram links on webpages?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, browser, handler, telegram

Using the link:

tg://resolve?domain=username1

It shows a popup to message the person in telegram, but is there a parameter to also attach a message to this handler? There isn't really any documentation for this it seems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As descibed in my previous [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60749367/5625547), there is almost nothing to find about the **Telegram URI Scheme**, except for some feeds were people complain about the fact it has been broken since an update;

1. This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31092657/how-to-send-message-from-website-to-telegram-app) that says `tg://msg?text=your MsG!"` should work on IOS only. There is an comment below saying it also works on android
2. [Twitter conversation](https://twitter.com/telegram/status/537953404900081664?lang=en), Telegram says `msg?` should work, but the'll have something better soon
3. [Telegram IOS github issue](https://github.com/TelegramMessenger/Telegram-iOS/issues/15)
4. [Telegram URI Scheme Helper](http://tsfkb.wikidot.com/tips:ios:urischeme)
5. [reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/Telegram/comments/933n0a/where_to_get_info_about_tg_links/) from 1 year ago, but they only shared the ['source file'](https://github.com/telegramdesktop/tdesktop/blob/a919737f6ef98b56cd7db41577ecfc269a60f444/Telegram/SourceFiles/core/click_handler_types.cpp#L61) which does not show something like `?msg=`.

Unforunaly Telegram stopped responding on the twitter conversation, until now there is no real documentation on this.

Comment: I know this is old, but I stumbled upon this question and found https://github.com/telegramdesktop/tdesktop/blob/13c00949ed29ba6da3d75badce04ba7d0124d9ae/Telegram/SourceFiles/core/local_url_handlers.cpp#L494 / https://github.com/telegramdesktop/tdesktop/blob/13c00949ed29ba6da3d75badce04ba7d0124d9ae/Telegram/SourceFiles/core/local_url_handlers.cpp#L577 interesting

Comment: And how to combine? for ex: domain + msg?